Using gmock matcher libraries with ament tests
My question
What is the idiomatic way to link ament_add_gmock tests against libraries which themselves need to be linked against gmock?
Context
We are currently migrating our C++ codebase from ROS1 (Noetic) to ROS2 (Humble).
We have a library of gmock matchers which we export from one package and use in several packages.
The problems we are encountering are all caused because matchers must be linked against gmock, and ament_add_gmock links tests against gmock, and it is not clear how to make the two play nicely together.
What we have tried
Not linking matchers against gmock
The solution which mostly works is to not link the matchers against gmock at all,
Utils package CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(utils)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_gmake_gmock REQUIRED)
  ament_find_gmock()

  add_library(test_utils src/matchers.cpp)
  # target_link_libraries(test_utils PUBLIC ${GMOCK_LIBRARIES})
  # target_link_directories(test_utils PUBLIC ${GMOCK_LIBRARY_DIRS})
  target_include_directories(test_utils PUBLIC ${GMOCK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  ament_export_targets(test_utils_targets HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  install(TARGETS test_utils EXPORT test_utils_targets LIBRARY DESTINATION lib ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME} INCLUDES DESTINATION include)
endif()

install(DIRECTORY include DESTINATION include)
ament_package()

main package CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(example)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(utils REQUIRED)

if (BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_cmake_gmock REQUIRED)

  ament_add_gmock(example test/test.cpp)
  ament_target_dependencies(example utils)
  target_include_directories(example PUBLIC include)
endif()

install(DIRECTORY include DESTINATION include)
ament_package()

This seems to work for most packages, but is not robust, and (depending on the vagaries of how other packages and dependencies are linked) regularly gives error messages of the form
/usr/bin/ld: <path>/test_utils.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::FormatMatcherDescription(...

i.e. test_utils has not been correctly linked against gmock.
Linking matchers against gmock
If we instead uncomment the lines
target_link_libraries(test_utils PUBLIC ${GMOCK_LIBRARIES})
target_link_directories(test_utils PUBLIC ${GMOCK_LIBRARY_DIRS})

then we get the errors
Target "test_utils" INTERFACE_LINK_DIRECTORIES property contains path:
  "<path>/build/utils/gmock"
which is prefixed in the build directory.

and
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "test_utils_targets" ...) includes target "test_utils" which requires target "gmock" that is not in any export set.

Linking against other copies of gmock
If we don't use ament_find_gmock() in utils, and instead link against the system gmock, then utils builds and installs fine, but trying to link test_utils into an ament_add_gmock test leads to ODR violations.
